# Data structure for reservation

Tags: algorithm, list, data-structures

Need a data Structure to store time based reservation on different resources.
It should support below query:

1. Latest reservation of a resource.
2. For a given time, find all the reservations on all resources.
3. ability to iterate on resource's next reservation

Answer (score 0):

I am currently thinking of using List of reservation for each resource, and adding new reservation at the end of list.

1. Latest reservation will be the last element of list [O(1)]
2. For each resource, do a binary search on reservation list. [O(m*log(n) m-number of resource, n- size of reservation list ]
3. Next element in list.

Interested in improving the time complexity for 2nd operation